# Ansible - Check if PermitRootLogin is equal to no

Tags: ansible, redhat

i'm new in Ansible

I would like to know if the value of PermitRootLogin = no in / etc / ssh / sshd_config

```
- hosts: RH7
  tasks:

  - name: read File
    shell: cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    register: PermitRootLogin no
```

help me pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this :

```
- hosts: RH7
  tasks:

  - name: read File
    shell: awk '/#PermitRootLogin/ {print $2}' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    register: PermitRootLogin

  - debug: msg="{{ PermitRootLogin.stdout }}"
```

`cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | awk '/#PermitRootLogin/ {print $2}'` : This command will give you the output of PermitRootLogin from the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

We will save the value in `PermitRootLogin` variable and can see it using the `debug` command.